# How do I disable Emmet's CSS Abbreviations in Sublime Text 2

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2, emmet

I really like how Emmet generates HTML based on 'CSS-like' strings but I don't want to use their CSS Abbreviations. Cause when I write a piece of css as follows:

```
li a|
```

And I press 'TAB', I want to get a Tab

```
li a    |
```

But with Emmet I get the following when I press Tab

```
li |-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none
```

How can I disable this functionality of Emmet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Emmet.sublime-settings` you have to update [`disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes`](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Emmet.sublime-settings#L29) property: add `source.css` to disable Tab trigger completely in CSS.

Also, if you’re on ST2, you may want to take a look at [`disable_tab_abbreviations_for_regexp`](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Emmet.sublime-settings#L34) preference due to some bugs in ST2 scope matcher.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed with package control, search for Package Control: Remove Package in the command palette. Otherwise you can just remove the Emmet directory.

If you wish to use a custom caption to access commands, create Default.sublime-commands in your User folder. Then insert something similar to the following.

```
[
    {
        "caption": "Package Control: Uninstall Package",
        "command": "remove_package"
    }
]
```

Of course, you can customize the command and caption as you see fit.

Or try like this: CTRL + SHIFT + P >> Remove Package >>
Select package to remove then press enter

Comment: That removes Emmet entirely. I think @user2642959 only wants to switch off certain features of Emmet.

Comment: have you tried to edit some file in the direcotry: Emmet.sublime-settings and delete the SNIPPETS

Comment: That is the problem, I can't find anything like that in the Emmet.sublime-settings.

Comment: Can you specify the row number which I can use to disable the CSS ? I only can find a general tab disable option: [14] disable_completions. But I`m more looking for something like disable_css_completions (which doesn't exists)

Comment: do you have the latest version? Do you have a 32 or 64 bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert a tab without triggering the tab trigger.

It’s documented in the [Sublime Text documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html#inserting-a-literal-tab-character).

Answer (score -1):

[Preferences.sublime-settings](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Preferences.sublime-settings)  - toggle on/off is there.